# VC call Javascript function in IE

Tags: javascript, c++, internet-explorer

I want execute JavaScript function on website by VC.

My c++ code can success execute standard JS function. (ex. "alert()")

But target JavaScript function is separated by website, website html code:

```
"<script src="//xxx/yyy/zzz.js"></script>"
```

My c++ code seems cant find function in "zzz.js" by "GetIDsOfNames()"

Have any way to get/execute functions in "zzz.js"?

Thanks.

Below is c++ code:

```
bool execJavascript(const CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> spDocument2, wstring wsFuncName, const       CArray <VARIANT, VARIANT&> &pArrVARIANT_Params) 
{
HRESULT hr = S_FALSE;
CComPtr<IDispatch> pScript;
hr = spDocument2-> get_Script(&pScript);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return false;

//(2)Get   Javascript   Function 
CComBSTR pCComBSTR(wsFuncName.c_str());
DISPID pDISPID;
hr = pScript->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &pCComBSTR, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &pDISPID);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return false;

//(3)Add   Parameters 
DISPPARAMS pDISPPARAMS;
memset(&pDISPPARAMS, 0, sizeof(pDISPPARAMS));

int intArgsCount_In = pArrVARIANT_Params.GetSize();
VARIANT* vParams = new VARIANT[intArgsCount_In]; 

for (int i = 0 ; i < intArgsCount_In ; i++) 
{ 
    vParams[i] = pArrVARIANT_Params.GetAt(i);
} 

//Params   Count 
pDISPPARAMS.cArgs = intArgsCount_In;
//Params   Array 
pDISPPARAMS.rgvarg = vParams;
//Name   Args   Count 
pDISPPARAMS.cNamedArgs = 0;

//(4)Invoke   Javascript   Method
EXCEPINFO pEXCEPINFO;
memset(&pEXCEPINFO, 0, sizeof(pEXCEPINFO));

CComVariant pCComVariant;
//Initialize   to   invalid   arg 
UINT nintArgErr = (UINT)-1;

hr = pScript->Invoke(pDISPID, IID_NULL, 0, DISPATCH_METHOD, &pDISPPARAMS, &pCComVariant, &pEXCEPINFO, &nintArgErr); 

delete[] pDISPPARAMS.rgvarg;
pScript.Release();

if(FAILED(hr))
    return false;
return true;
}
```

Comment: the code seems okay, maybe an error in the function name ? Or maybe you need a variable to call the function ?

Comment: I checked, code failed at "GetIDsOfNames()". Function name is correct and no need any parameter. Function is written in "zzz.js". Thanks.

Comment: maybe show the javascript function you're trying to call ?

Comment: function doAjaxLogin() {
      $.post("/ic/api/signinx.jsp", $("#loginForm").serialize(),
   function(data){
 if (data.status == "true") {
  if (data.url) {
   location.href = data.url;
   return;
  }
  performLogin();
 } else {
  if (data.url)
   location.href = data.url;
 }
    }, "json");
 
    }

Comment: I found root cause. IE9 or Newer version didn't support "GetIDsOfNames()". Reference [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/27987dc5-14a9-4be9-a834-5b8329ce3d11/idispatchinvoke-not-working-in-ie9), thanks all.